# How to loop through characters in stream C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

So, I am writing code that takes in a file from the user, removes all punctuation. Make the file lower case and finds all the unique words. The problem is not working correctly and I dont know why. I does not print out the correct number of unique values

```
// convert charater to lowercase 
void convert(char& ch){

   ch = tolower(ch); 

 }
 int main(){

    typedef map<string,int> siMap;
    typedef pair<siMap::iterator, bool>ibPair;
    typedef siMap::value_type kvpair; 
    siMap myMap;


    string fileName1;
    string fileName2; 
    string value; 
    char ch;

   // get user input 
   cout << "Please enter the first file Name: "; //asking for a file name 
   cin >> fileName1; 
   ifstream infile1;
   infile1.open(fileName1.c_str());

   //remove all punctuations 
    while (infile1.get(ch))
    {
        if (isalpha(ch) || isspace(ch)){
              convert(ch);
        } 

        else{
            infile1.ignore(ch);  
       }
        infile1 >> value;
        myMap[value]++; 
    }

 /*
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << infile1[i];

} */

cout << " Map size is :" << myMap.size() << endl;

cout << "Please enter the second file Name: "; //asking for a file name 
cin >> fileName2; 
ifstream infile;
infile.open(fileName2.c_str());



}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: It would be easier if you read the entire line into a string, and then use `std::istringstream` to process each unique word.

Comment: See [this example](http://ideone.com/NivQ0b) on how to proceed with the part of storing unique words into a map.   Note that usage of `istringstream` to be used as the parser -- do a search on SO and other sites, and you see that this is the method most often used.  You still have to write the code to change the characters that was read in and to make them lower case before storing in a map.

Comment: Get rid of the map.  First just try reading and printing words.  Right now you are mixing get() and >> so it is unlikely that you are getting whole words properly.

Answer (score -1):

can you provide your first input file? also remember to close file after you done with it. For debugging part you might want to use map iterator to find out which word is missing.

```
// convert charater to lowercase 
void convert(char& ch)
{
    ch = tolower(ch);
}

int main()
{
    typedef map<string,int> siMap;
    typedef pair<siMap::iterator, bool>ibPair;
    typedef siMap::value_type kvpair; 
    siMap myMap;

    string fileName1;
    string fileName2; 
    string value; 
    char ch;

    // get user input 
    cout << "Please enter the first file Name: "; //asking for a file name 
    cin >> fileName1; 
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName1.c_str());
    std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()   ) );

    //remove all punctuations
    for(std::string::iterator it = content.begin(); it != content.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (isalpha(*it))
        {
            convert(*it);
        } 
        else
        {
            *it = ' ';  
        }
    }

    //now working on your map
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str (content);
    string singleWord;
    while (ss >> singleWord)
    {
        myMap[singleWord]++; 
    }
    cout << " Map size is :" << myMap.size() << endl;

    cout << "blahblah" << endl;
    for (std::map<string,int>::iterator it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

    cout << "Please enter the second file Name: "; //asking for a file name 
    cin >> fileName2; 
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(fileName2.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Not sure it would change the behavior of your function. but seems like you need to replace a space between 2 words if i.e xxx,yy counts as two words